# Is the RF/DC power on/off sequence for my simple radio beacon design good enough?

Tags: power, rf, analog, integrated-circuit, soft-starter

I'm using a RFPA5542 PA module. Does the power on/off sequence have to be followed exactly? Do I risk damage to the IC? I am delaying PA_EN by 2ms by an RC circuit of R13 and C5 and that is all. The signal source has no delayed startup. Should I put a power-on delay circuit for the signal source that feeds this power amplifier or is ok without any changes?

[link to project github here](https://github.com/AGH-Space-Systems/Boczek-PCB)

[link to IC datasheet](https://www.qorvo.com/products/d/da001019)

[image: Power On Sequence from datasheet]

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 0):

Per the datasheet, as it says in even the exact section you screenshotted, the PA-EN signal *must* be applied before the RF input is applied.

[image: The same image as in the question, with lines highlighted that say "Turn on PA enable prior to applying RF signal." and "Turn off RF signal prior to turning off PA enable."]

You don't necessarily need a power-up delay to the RF generator (though that would work), but you *do* need to prevent any RF from reaching the device before PA-EN is asserted. You could do this, for instance, by using an RF switch (or an RF relay, if the power is too high to handle with a simple semiconductor switch) to dump the incoming RF signal into a terminated load before you're ready for it.